# How to extract sessionId from Citrus HttpRequest

Tags: httprequest, sessionid, citrus-framework

I tried to test the a set of REST services using Citrus Java DSL. After authentication the services expect the same, valid session id of the first request.
On the server side I can see, that there exists a random session-id, but at the second request, the session-id is null.
I've tried to set *handleCookies* to true in the endpoint configuration and tried to extract some header information (set-cookie) but without success. The *EndpointConfiguration* is reused during the different requests.

```
CitrusEndpoints.http()
   .client()
   .handleCookies(true)
```

How can I force the Endpoint to reuse the negotiated session-id or how can I extract it from the request / response?

Thanks in advance for any ideas and hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response to your 1st request should have a header set

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=ABCDEFG;path=/api/foo
```

You can extract this information in your receive operation

```
http()
    .client(todoClient)
    .receive()
    .response(HttpStatus.OK)
    .extractFromHeader("Set-Cookie", "cookie")
    .payload("{ \"foo\": \"bar\" }");
```

After that we have to post process the new `${cookie}` value in order to extract the actual session id name and value into a new variable `${sessionId}`.

```
createVariable("sessionId", "citrus:substringBefore(${cookie}, ';')");
```

Now we have a variable `${sessionId}` that only contains the name and value of the session id - in our example this is `JSESSIONID=ABCDEFG`.

In further requests you can use the variable in order to set proper `Cookie` header information

```
http()
    .client(todoClient)
    .send()
    .get("/api/foo")
    .header("Cookie", "${sessionId}")
    .accept(ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.getMimeType());
```

Comment: Thanks, Christoph, I tried it out, but it did not work. After some more testing also calling the services via a browser it seems that - using the browser, the JSESSIONID is part of the request header and not included in the response. But when I change your code in order to extract the cookie from the request Citrus always returns with an error message, that header element could not be found in header.

Comment: This means that the client creates the session id in the very first request and should continue to use it? If so, you can just create a variable value (using randomString or randomUUID Citrus functions) and set the "Cookie" header in the first and all following requests as seen in the last code snippet of my answer.

Comment: Yes that was the problem. I resolved it with custom config, so that in case of integration test scenarios the server adds the sessionId in the response header. Another question based on the first one: I have seen that it is possible to use _global_ variables. When using the snippet `createVariable("sessionId", "citrus:substringBefore(${cookie}, ';')");`, is it possible to reuse the _sessionId_ variable between different _@CitrusTest_ test cases?

Comment: I think I found a solution to the variable problem. When using TestRunner instead of TestDesigner I'm able to inject the TestContext. After calling the _createVariable_ function, I can get the variable from _context_ and add it as a _globalVariable_ to the context. Doing it like this, I'm able to read the global variable from the context also in other TestCase methods. `createVariable("sessionId", "citrus:substringBefore('${cookie}', ';')");
 String jSessionId= context.getVariable("sessionId", String.class); context.getGlobalVariables().put("jSessionId", jSessionId);`